# Referencing an movieclip with the same name in an array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I realise this is very basic but i need a quick way of referencing all my objects in an array,
I have a series of movieclips with instance names "block1" "block2"... etc.

I there a quick way to reference these in an array something like "block"+1 ?
or even "block" then 1 to 12 ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your asking, but if you want to populate an array with references to your movieclips (that are name sequentially), then you can use the [getChildByName()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29) method. This method takes an instance name as a string, and gives you back the reference to the displayobject if it finds one. So you could do something like this:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    var item:DisplayObject = this.getChildByName('block' + i);
    // Use item here. You probably want to make sure item is not null first.
}
```

Comment: Why +1? The OP clearly states that these objects are MovieClips. I'd cast it to MovieClip.

Comment: MovieClips ARE DisplayObjects! What have you got against polymorphism Roy?